# Cumulative sum only applying on 1 column python

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I would like to apply cumsum on 1 specific column only since I have got other values in different columns that must stay the same.

This is the script that I have so far

```
df.groupby(by=['name','day']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
```

However this script results in that all of my columns in my pandas df will cumulate. The only column which must cumulate sum is `data`.

As requested, here is some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["880022443344556677787", "880022443344556677782", "880022443344556677787",
                          "880022443344556677782", "880022443344556677787", "880022443344556677782",
                          "880022443344556677781"],
                   'Month': ["201701", "201701", "201702", "201702", "201703", "201703", "201703"],
                   'Usage': [20, 40, 100, 50, 30, 30, 2000],
                   'Sec': [10, 15, 20, 1, 5, 6, 30]})

                      ID   Month  Sec  Usage
0  880022443344556677787  201701   10     20
1  880022443344556677782  201701   15     40
2  880022443344556677787  201702   20    100
3  880022443344556677782  201702    1     50
4  880022443344556677787  201703    5     30
5  880022443344556677782  201703    6     30
6  880022443344556677781  201703   30   2000
```

Desired output

```
                      ID   Month  Sec  Usage
0  880022443344556677787  201701   10     20
1  880022443344556677782  201701   15     40
2  880022443344556677787  201702   20    120
3  880022443344556677782  201702    1     90
4  880022443344556677787  201703    5    150
5  880022443344556677782  201703    6    120
6  880022443344556677781  201703   30   2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for cols where NOT need `cumsum` - I dynamically find them by `list comprehension`:

```
cumsum_col = 'Usage'
df1 = df.groupby(by=['ID','Month'], sort=False).sum()
cols = [col for col in df1.columns if col != cumsum_col]

df1 = df1.set_index(cols, append=True).groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().reset_index()
print (df1)
                      ID   Month  Sec  Usage
0  880022443344556677787  201701   10     20
1  880022443344556677782  201701   15     40
2  880022443344556677787  201702   20    120
3  880022443344556677782  201702    1     90
4  880022443344556677787  201703    5    150
5  880022443344556677782  201703    6    120
6  880022443344556677781  201703   30   2000
```

EDIT:

```
cumsum_col = 'Usage'
df2 = df.groupby(by=['ID','Month'], sort=False).sum()
cols = [col for col in df2.columns if col != cumsum_col]
df1 = df2.set_index(cols, append=True).groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
df1 = df2.assign(Usage_cumsum = df1.reset_index(level=2, drop=True)).reset_index()
print (df1)
                      ID   Month  Sec  Usage  Usage_cumsum
0  880022443344556677787  201701   10     20            20
1  880022443344556677782  201701   15     40            40
2  880022443344556677787  201702   20    100           120
3  880022443344556677782  201702    1     50            90
4  880022443344556677787  201703    5     30           150
5  880022443344556677782  201703    6     30           120
6  880022443344556677781  201703   30   2000          2000
```

EDIT1:

In your sample data is not aggregate `sum`, so data are a bit modified (solution is similar, but not same as another):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["880022443344556677787", "880022443344556677782", "880022443344556677787",
                          "880022443344556677782", "880022443344556677787", "880022443344556677782",
                          "880022443344556677781"],
                   'Month': ["201701", "201701", "201701", "201702", "201703", "201701", "201703"],
                   'Usage': [20, 40, 100, 50, 30, 30, 2000],
                   'Sec': [10, 15, 20, 1, 5, 6, 30]})

print (df)
                      ID   Month  Sec  Usage
0  880022443344556677787  201701   10     20
1  880022443344556677782  201701   15     40
2  880022443344556677787  201701   20    100
3  880022443344556677782  201702    1     50
4  880022443344556677787  201703    5     30
5  880022443344556677782  201701    6     30
6  880022443344556677781  201703   30   2000
```

```
#aggregate sum to all columns
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Month']).sum() 
print (df1)
                              Sec  Usage
ID                    Month             
880022443344556677781 201703   30   2000
880022443344556677782 201701   21     70
                      201702    1     50
880022443344556677787 201701   30    120
                      201703    5     30

#aggregate cumcum to Usage column only 
s = df1.groupby(level=0)['Usage'].cumsum()
print (s)
ID                     Month 
880022443344556677781  201703    2000
880022443344556677782  201701      70
                       201702     120
880022443344556677787  201701     120
                       201703     150
Name: Usage, dtype: int64
```

```
#join cumsum series to aggregate df1
df3 = df1.join(s, rsuffix='_cumsum').reset_index()
print (df3)
                      ID   Month  Sec  Usage  Usage_cumsum
0  880022443344556677781  201703   30   2000          2000
1  880022443344556677782  201701   21     70            70
2  880022443344556677782  201702    1     50           120
3  880022443344556677787  201701   30    120           120
4  880022443344556677787  201703    5     30           150
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an additional column with the cum sum data instead of replacing it?

Comment: Not sure what is going on but when I apply it to my df your first method is working but the new one with an additional column with the cumsum returns with `NaN` values. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: So it seems your real data have more columns, so need change `df1.reset_index(level=[2,3,4], drop=True)` - each level for additional column. But I modify another solution, give me a sec.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        name=list('aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb'),
        day=np.tile(np.arange(2).repeat(4), 2),
        data=np.arange(16)
    ))
```

First, you perform your `cumsum` over a specific column by naming the column after the `groupby` statement.

Second, you can add this back to the dataframe `df` with `join`

```
d2 = df.groupby(['name', 'day']).data.sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum()

df.join(d2, on=['name', 'day'], rsuffix='_cum')

    data  day name  data_cum
0      0    0    a         6
1      1    0    a         6
2      2    0    a         6
3      3    0    a         6
4      4    1    a        28
5      5    1    a        28
6      6    1    a        28
7      7    1    a        28
8      8    0    b        38
9      9    0    b        38
10    10    0    b        38
11    11    0    b        38
12    12    1    b        92
13    13    1    b        92
14    14    1    b        92
15    15    1    b        92
```

Answer (score 1):

You can already do the cumulative sum (`'cumsum'`) as an aggregation to the `df.groupby`. You need to give it `'cumsum'` as a string as an aggregation function to the 'data' column.

```
df.groupby(['name','day']).agg({'data': 'cumsum'})
```

Comment: It is wrong, because first need aggregate `sum` and then groupby by first level only for aggregate cumsum.